# Lightning Component Redirect

Tags: lightning-aura-components, redirect

Good afternoon!
I need to redirect the user to a new page from a click of a standard button. However, I need this redirection to be done in the same window.

To do this, I created a button pointing to my lightning redirect component:

[image]

The redirect occurs correctly, but for 2 seconds the component appears on the screen, and this cannot happen:

[image]

[image]

After this white square appears the page is redirected.
In the **helper** of my component I perform an apex query to know which page I should direct. Could this be delaying the process? Or is there a way to make the component not appear but perform what it needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your redirect code look like? Are you redirecting to another page in Salesforce or somewhere else on the web?

Unfortunately, you will always receive that white panel pop up when you click the Action but you can use CSS to make it fully transparent. Additionally, you can also use the Close Quick Action to close the panel instantly.

**Try adding this to your aura component markup to make it transparent:**

```
    <!-- Make modal background transparent -->
<aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-backdrop {
    background: rgba(43, 40, 38, 0) !important;
    }
    .backgroundSpinner{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    }
    .modal-body {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    }
    .closeIcon {
    display:none !important;
    }
    .desktop {
    overflow: visible !important;
    }
</aura:html>
```

**Try adding this to your controller function to close the panel:**

```
$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
```